# How to print Microsoft Word's gridlines?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-office-2016, grid, microsoft-word-2016

I am trying to print gridlines in `Microsoft Word`. The gridlines are shown in the document, but I can't print them. They become invisible when print them.

Here is what I am trying to print: 
[image]

---

If I manually create gridlines using tables or background picture (in this case I have to print the gridlines at first and then print text on it), text is not alligned to gridlines properly and it looks messy. That is why it would be much better to print Microsoft's gridlines with text. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open MS Word
2. Go to Design Tab
3. Page Background
4. Page Color
5. Fill Effects
6. Pattern Tab
7. Select Grid
8. Change Foreground as per requirement

And done!

Answer (score 2):

[How to Print Gridlines in MS Word](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/print-gridlines-ms-word-54819.html)

> Step 1 Open Microsoft Word. To print an existing document with
>   gridlines, click the “File” tab, select “Open,” then browse to and
>   double-click the Word file. Otherwise, Word starts you with a blank
>   document. Add text and images as desired.
>
> Step 2 Click the “View” tab. Click a check into the “Gridlines” box in
>   the Show section of the ribbon. The gridlines now appear on your Word
>   document, but won’t print. Make any changes to the document as
>   desired, such as aligning your images in the grid.
>
> Related Reading: How to See "No Mark Up" in MS Word
>
> Step 3 Click the “One Page” button on the View tab’s ribbon. This lets
>   you see your entire Word document. Press the “Alt” key and the “Print
>   Screen” keys on your keyboard together, to make a copy of the Word
>   document on the screen.
>
> Step 4 Open Paint from the operating system’s Accessories folder.
>   Click the “Paste” button on the ribbon, which pastes in the Word
>   document with the gridlines. Click the “Select” button the ribbon.
>   Draw a rectangle around just the Word document page and click the
>   “Crop” button on the ribbon. This is essential if you’ve gotten
>   another monitor, your sys tray, an instant messenger window or
>   something else in your Word document screen capture. After the crop,
>   you’re left with a replica of the Word document with the gridlines.
>
> Step 5 Click the Paint button’s drop-down menu and select “Print.”
>   Choose your printer from the options, select how many copies to print
>   and click the “Print” button.

Comment: I printed this way and the quality is quite poor. Text is not accurate. After these copy-pasting and crop procedures text/picture became fuzzy and not readable.