# Print MS Word gridlines?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, printing

Word has a very convenient gridlines feature which enables you to view gridlines of any size you like, and align elements in your document with them. You can enable it in Layout-tab>Align>View gridlines.

These gridlines are not present when printing however, yet an option to enable their printing seems like an obvious feature to have.

I have looked far and wide and found no way to do it. There are many solutions online claiming to work, yet they simply don't. [This MS Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/print-gridlines-d825b45c-daeb-41f5-949b-e723e3ff10bb#:%7E:text=On%20the%20Design%20tab%2C%20click,select%20the%20Gridlines%20check%20box.) offers a solution (with an error in it- "Page Setup" is under the Layout tab and not the Design tab). But it simply falls flat on its second step, since a "Print Setup" tab doesn't exist in the "Page Setup" dialog box.

[This superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1058049/how-to-print-microsoft-words-gridlines) doesn't contain a satisfying answer either. The first reply is linking an article that offers taking a screenshot of the page as a solution, which seems extremely archaic and worsens quality. The second reply offers to circumvent the grindlines feature itself and just stick a background on the Word document that looks like a grid, yet lacks all the great features and settings.

I've tried looking for solutions on both google and youtube, yet got none. Does anyone know how to do this? Printing gridlines seems like an extremely simple and obvious feature to have considering MS Word *already has* gridlines.

Comment: Which grid "great features and settings" would you expect while printing? You can't edit the document from the print dialog.

Comment: `[MS Support article][1]`, states:
> Visio Plan 2 Visio Professional 2021 Visio Standard 2021 Visio Professional 2019 Visio Standard 2019 Visio Professional 2016 Visio Standard 2016 Visio Professional 2013 Visio 2013 Visio 2007  

... so only valid for Visio, not word.

Answer (score 3):

### Word does not have this capability. Those gridlines are intended to be non-printing.

*Those gridlines are intended to help you in placing printing items on your page. The idea is that they will not be seen in the final product.*

You could create and use graph paper [templates](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm).

You can [download some templates from my website](https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#graph). The screenshot below is from the quarter-inch template.

[image: screenhot]

Here is a link to [Word MVP Bill Coan's macro](http://web.archive.org/web/20070421084938/http:/pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=596) to create these. A printout of my modified version the macro is included in the download package on my website and below. There are no active macros in the download.

**Here my modified version of the macro:**

> ```
> Sub GraphPaperCreate()
> '   TechTrax - Bill Coan
> '   http://web.archive.org/web/20070421084938/http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=596
> '   modified by Charles Kenyon to:
> '       reduce margins to .25
> '       lighter line weight (.3 points rather than 2 points)
> '       grid is set behind text in case there is text
> '
> ' Sets margins at .25"  Charles Kenyon
> '
>     With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
>         .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(0.25)
>         .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(0.25)
>         .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(0.25)
>         .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(0.25)
>     End With
>
>     'Declare variables
>     Dim sglBeginX As Single
>     Dim sglEndX As Single
>     Dim sglBeginY As Single
>     Dim sglEndY As Single
>     Dim Interval As Single
>     Dim LineCount As Integer
>     Dim VerticalGridLines As Integer
>     Dim HorizontalGridLines As Integer
>     Dim GridWidth As Single
>     Dim GridHeight As Single
>     Dim UserChoice As String
>     Dim oLine As Shape
>
>     'set the line weight, in points
>     Const LINE_WEIGHT As Long = 0.5   'changed from Integer = 2 by Charles Kenyon - this is the minimum
>
>     'set whether to delete the old grid,
>     '(assuming there is one)
>     Const DELETE_OLD_GRID As Boolean = True
>
>     'Delete the old grid
>     If DELETE_OLD_GRID Then
>        On Error Resume Next
>        ActiveDocument.range.ShapeRange.Delete
>        On Error GoTo 0
>     End If
>
>     'Prompt the user to specify the size of squares desired
> PromptUser:
>     UserChoice = InputBox _
>     ("Enter size of squares in points:" & vbLf & vbLf & _
>        "(Value must be between 1 and 72)" & vbLf & _
>        "9 points = 1/8 inch" & vbLf & _
>        "12 points = 1/6 inch" & vbLf & _
>        "18 points = 1/4 inch" & vbLf & _
>        "24 points = 1/3 inch" & vbLf & _
>        "36 points = 1/2 inch" & vbLf & _
>        "48 points = 2/3 inch" & vbLf & _
>        "72 points = one inch", "Create graph paper")
>
>     'If the size requested is outside the allowed range,
>     'then go back and prompt the user again,
>     'but if user has clicked cancel, then quit
>     If IsNumeric(UserChoice) Then
>        Interval = Val(UserChoice)
>        If Interval > 72 Or Interval < 2 Then
>           MsgBox "Value must be between 2 and 72.", _
>             vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Value out of range"
>           GoTo PromptUser
>        End If
>     ElseIf UserChoice = "" Then
>        GoTo EndGracefully
>     Else
>        GoTo PromptUser
>     End If
>
>     'Calculate beginning and ending positions
>     'based on page size and margins
>     With ActiveDocument.Sections.First.PageSetup
>        sglBeginX = .LeftMargin
>        sglEndX = .PageWidth - .RightMargin
>        sglBeginY = .TopMargin
>        sglEndY = .PageHeight - .BottomMargin
>     End With
>
>     'Calculate how many squares of the requested size
>     'can fit in the available area
>     HorizontalGridLines = Int((sglEndY - sglBeginY) / Interval)
>     VerticalGridLines = Int((sglEndX - sglBeginX) / Interval)
>
>     'Calculate the size of the finished grid, based on
>     'size of the number of lines and the size of the squares
>     GridWidth = VerticalGridLines * Interval
>     GridHeight = HorizontalGridLines * Interval
>
>     'draw the horizontal lines
>     For LineCount = 0 To HorizontalGridLines
>        Set oLine = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddLine( _
>           BeginX:=sglBeginX, _
>           BeginY:=sglBeginY + LineCount * Interval, _
>           EndX:=sglBeginX + GridWidth, _
>           EndY:=sglBeginY + LineCount * Interval)
>        oLine.line.Weight = LINE_WEIGHT
>        oLine.ZOrder msoSendBehindText   'Charles Kenyon
>     Next LineCount
>
>     'draw the vertical lines
>     For LineCount = 0 To VerticalGridLines
>        Set oLine = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddLine( _
>           BeginX:=sglBeginX + LineCount * Interval, _
>           BeginY:=sglBeginY, _
>           EndX:=sglBeginX + LineCount * Interval, _
>           EndY:=sglBeginY + GridHeight)
>        oLine.line.Weight = LINE_WEIGHT
>        oLine.ZOrder msoSendBehindText   'Charles Kenyon
>     Next LineCount
>
>     'release the oLine object from memory
>     Set oLine = Nothing
>
>     'end gracefully
> EndGracefully:
>
> End Sub
> ```

The grid produced could be placed in a header or footer to be background to ordinary text.

- [Instructions for Installing Macros From Websites or Forums](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) by MVP Graham Mayor
- [Install/Employ vba Procedures (Macros)](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html) by Greg Maxey